# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Filter using "and" and "or"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Trying to create a calendar with a view where the category is equal to Business travel and it encompasses 5 employees (my team).

It makes sense to me, but apparently this logic doesn't work in SharePoint: **Category is equal to "Business Travel" AND (Employee is Equal to X OR Employee is equal to XX, etc).**

How do I accomplish this in SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try referencing [this solution](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/11/understanding-filters-in-sharepoint-list-views-aspx/). The basic explanation that it gives is that when you set filter values on a view in a SP list, the operators work opposite to what you would expect. IE - it groups the conditions prior to the condition that is different.

So if you try switching to (Employee is Equal to X OR Employee is Equal to Y OR Employee is Equal to Z) AND Category is equal to "Business Travel" then the OR conditions should be grouped correctly and the filter should work.

If this doesn't work, you can always do a work-around by creating a hidden column that dynamically populates with a given value if the Employee column is equal to one of your 5 team members. Then just use that column value in the view filter.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not a very intuitive way to group conditions, but as long as it works...